# How to check if a values of Series are part of a column in a Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My series, `s`, has values like:

```
Num
1310005
10005640
33410018556
37110008380
10005964
10001372
16720000015
10006164
10005244
```

My DataFrame, `df`,  has values like:

```
Col1                     Col2
13100059609134686926     2020-04-13
1821000522018596119796   2020-04-11
19100059609134059575     2020-04-13
259100185562459764794    2020-04-14
```

I want to check if values of my Series are part of `Col1` of my dataframe, if yes, then which value is it.

For example:
`1310005` is a part of `13100059609134686926`. Once found, I would like to add it as an extra column.

```
    Col1                     Col2            Col3
    13100059609134686926     2020-04-13     1310005
    1821000522018596119796   2020-04-11     NA
    19100059609134059575     2020-04-13     NA
    259100185562459764794    2020-04-14     NA
```

I tried `df.isin()` but that did not give a proper result.
Another option is using double for loop, but there has to be a better way to do it.
Any suggestions?

Comment: can u share data where num is in col1? i assume the num must be contiguous when searching in col1

Comment: You can use pandas apply (which is kind of one for loop) rather than a double loop.

Comment: Can you explain what is what output you want . with an example .   df[df['col1'].isin(Num)]['Col1'].tolist() should give you what you want.